# Reading results of SP with OdbcDataReader gives Error 22018 - Error in assignment

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, odbc

Ok I don't get this. I haven't used ODBC classes before but figuered it's nothing special for basic use. And it does work except in this case.

I need to execute stored procedure without parameters via ODBC connection and get the results, parse the rows into objects and insert them in my local DB. And it worked with test data but now fails with live data, while customer is able to execute the same PS via some other tool... The real trouble is that I have to run it on live server, so I can't debug, instead I created small project which writes output into TextBox. Anyway, here's the code:

```
var ODBCConnection = new OdbcConnection();
ODBCConnection.ConnectionString = "something...";
//using command "exec schema.spName" or "exec schema.spName()" or "{ call schema.spName()}" runs the procedure
//putting only name "schema.spName" gives ERROR [42000]
    var cmd = new OdbcCommand("exec schema.spName())", ODBCConnection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    DbReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

int fCount = DbReader.FieldCount;
infoBox1.Text += System.Environment.NewLine + "Results:";
for (int i = 0; i < fCount; i++)
{
  String fName = DbReader.GetName(i);
  infoBox1.Text += fName + "|";
}
```

This list all the column names in result and there are 20 columns.

```
while (DbReader.Read())
{
 var row = new RowClass();
  for (int i = 0; i < fCount; i++)
    {
      object val = DbReader.GetValue(i);
      //check which column this is and parse it to set properties of RowClass
      //Expected values are string, int and decimal
    }
}
```

This works for the first 10 rows but breaks when it tries to read for following columns with error:

```
ERROR [22018] [Cache ODBC][State : 22005][Native Code 22005]
[path to .exe]
Error in assignment
```

No StackTrace no InnerException.

I tried skipping 11th column because it started there, but breaks for every column after the first 10.
I am clueless... if it read there are 20 fields then wtf... null values are not problem because it returns DBNull, it works on other places (not executing SP but doing select queries).

Client executed sp connectin from same net environment and send me picshot, and csv of data. Nothing strane in data itself.

Anyone had this before? Should I use something else for instead of OdbcDataReader?

Thank you.

Comment: With .NET and SQL Server, SqlClient is the best provider to use.

Comment: Can I use it without direct access to SQL? Admin on client side set up connection using ODBC Administrator so I thought I need OdbcConnection to communicate. Connection string starts with `Dsn=name;`

Comment: You can't use an ODBC DSN with SqlClient. Instead, you would specify the server, database, and authentication settings in the connection string directly without the external DSN dependency.

Comment: That is not yet the option, but I sure wish it is

Comment: ODBC error 220118 is "invalid character for cast specification". It seems there is a data type mismatch but I don't see anything in the code you provided that would explain why the driver would return this error.  Which ODBC driver the DSN is configured to use?  It might help if you post the proc code. BTW, the command syntax you posted looks odd since one typically specifies only the proc name when executing a proc via an RPC call.

Comment: You're right: when studying how to use ODBC I only found examples with proc name, but that gives me `ERROR [42000]` so I played around a bit. I edited my code for more info about it. I use ODBC reading on other DBs without a problem, so my guess is something about connection/driver. I don't have access to proc code. I'll ask about drier and maybe even SQL version from where I try to read...

Comment: Oh, I remembered I can check in ODBC admin. The driver is: InterSystems ODBC

Comment: Your question was tagged SQL Server but I don't believe that is what InterSystems ODBC accesses.  The error is returned by the driver so the problem may be either due to a driver bug or inconsistent meta-data returned by the server.

Comment: In the end it was SQL database, but `Date` column was mapped as `INT` in ODBC, which caused cast error. I didn't know it would cause all subsequent columns to break also. Thx for tips about error codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I managed to figure it out thanks to customer admin who was executing the same procedure by some browser SQL tool. There I saw that 11th column was of type `Date`. ODBC returned type `INT` for that column. So I had to call another admin who set up ODBC and he changed column type to `varchar` so now it finally works.

I guess I can now assume how DataReader works if one wrong column type made all subsequent columns impossible to read as well.

I don't feel like accepting my own answer, so if someone would be kind enough to give me few links about how ODBC works and how `DataReader` works, not just how to use it, and maybe can quote some text that explains this behavior for this kind of mistake...